# Angular 2- Bind to minlength property oif HTML tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I was thinking about writing some reusable components for Forms. Label/Input for things like firstName, lastName, email.
I'm having a problem binding to minlength.
Here's part of the code:

```
<input 
        ngControl="name"
        #name="ngForm"
        type="text" 
        class="form-control" 
        id="name"
        required
        minlength="{{min}}">
```

I get the following error message:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'minlength' since it isn't a known native property ("
        id="name"
        required
        [ERROR ->]minlength="{{min}}">
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pattern` attribute, with `RegExp`.

- Declare the regex in your controller and refer to it from the view

`regExp = ".{5,}";` `e.g. --> 5 characters minimum`

```
<input 
    ngControl="name"
    #name="ngForm"
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    id="name"
    required
    pattern="{{ regExp }}">
```

- or use it directly inside the view:
  `pattern=".{5,}"`

https://plnkr.co/edit/x5hwYzeMCkycdJs9YfW7?p=preview

Comment: This almost works for me. Except that I can't submit the form because it keeps giving me an error message asking me to "Please match the requested format". I'm entering "abcdef" which is 6 chars long.

Comment: @Shanie I've added plunker link. It works just fine.

Comment: It sure does. I think the problem was with "regExp = new RegExp(".{5,}");".   If I set "regExp = ".{5,}";" then it works so it seems you need to pass a string rather that a regex object.

Comment: Just did it. Thanks for the help. Do you you know how to use pattern to raise an error message? I had been using: *ngIf="email.errors.minlength"

Comment: @Shanie Will look for it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `[attr.minlength]="min"`, because this is elements attribute, not a native property

Comment: This works but I have 2 questions for you. Can you explain why it works (I don't really get it)? How do I use it to generate an error message? previously I had:      <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">                    
                    Name must be at least {{min}} characters long 
                </div>

Comment: minlength is not a native attribute so I doubt it would *actually* work.

Comment: @Shanie You can find when to use attributes binding in angular official guide here 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings. To validate input you should user Reactive Forms classes like FormControl, FormGroup etc or use basic Forms module and check form errors to which that input is related to

Answer (score 0):

We specify one-way bindings to DOM properties using square brackets and template expressions.

Please make the changes as `minlength="{{min}}"`  to `[minlength]="min"`

This diagram explains Angular2 property binding to some extent

[image: This diagram explains Angular2 property binding to some extent]

Comment: I've tried that as well and got this: EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'minlength' since it isn't a known native property ("
            id="name"
            required
            [ERROR ->][minlength]="min">
Is it something to do with the minlength property itself because I can use the min variable with interpolation {{min}} as in: Name must be at least {{min}} characters long

Comment: That picture you have posted has nothing with the OP issue.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find a serial killer.